# The usage of "zu"

Tags: usage, preposition

I know the usage of *von*, genitive case and possessive pronoun, but when and how should I use *zu* in the sense of possession?

For example:

> Demonstration **zum** Weltfrauentag
>   Prüfung **zum** Steuerberater
>   Übung **zu** Wortarten

Comment: "zu" is a preposition. first example means "to the occasion of": "Demonstration zum Anlass des Frauentages". 2nd example means "to become": "Prüfung, um anerkannter Steuerberater zu werden." 3rd example means "dealing with": "Übung zum Thema Wortarten".

Comment: There is not a single case with a sense of possession among your 3 examples :)

Comment: Now I realise it is somehow like an expression in English:  "Opinion 'on' that issue" , "A father 'to' five children", "Reason 'for' something"

Answer (score 2):

None of your examples actually indicate a possession. The demostration is *on the occasion of* the International Women’s Day, the examination is *to become* a tax advisor and the exercise is *concerning* word types.

All three of these could also take *von*, but that would change the meaning in every case to something much closer to possession.

Answer (score -1):

Demonstration zum Weltfrauentag
Prüfung zum Steuerberater
Übung zu Wortarten

As usual understanding what the actual word means in context helps a lot.

> Übung zu Wortarten --> Exercise in regards TO word types (about)
>
> Prüfung zum Steuerberater --> I don't know what that is supposed to mean.
>
> Demonstration zum Weltfrauentag --> Demonstrate at/during the Weltfrauentag. (Time)